# Frequency of one specific value in a DataFrame column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am attempting to count the frequency of one specific value 'Devonport' in the column 'Ground' in a data set. I have tried to use the Groupby function and the value.counts() and it is only returning the first and last 5 unique values in the column which has a total of 173 unique values. I know there is one occurrence of 'Devonport' in the column 'Ground' because I opened the csv file and filtered on the column, but I am unable to get the function to return this in jupyter notebook.

Any help would be great!  I'm very new to python - just taking a course in it now.

```
occur=csv.groupby(['Ground']).size().T
Ground
Aberdeen         11
Abu Dhabi        37
Adelaide         82
Ahmedabad        24
Albion            5
                 ..
Vijayawada        1
Visakhapatnam    11
Wellington       56
Whangarei         1
Worcester         3
Length: 173, dtype: int64


print(csv.Ground.value_counts())
Sharjah       228
Dhaka         156
Sydney        154
Melbourne     147
Harare        136
             ... 
Hove            1
Nairobi         1
Vijayawada      1
Kwekwe          1
Lucknow         1

Name: Ground, Length: 173, dtype: int64
csv['Ground'].value_counts('Devonport')
Sharjah       0.057986
Dhaka         0.039674
Sydney        0.039166
Melbourne     0.037386
Harare        0.034588
                ...   
Hove          0.000254
Nairobi       0.000254
Vijayawada    0.000254
Kwekwe        0.000254
Lucknow       0.000254
Name: Ground, Length: 173, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
csv['Ground'].value_counts()['Devonport']
```